# Consumer<?> and Consumer<T> seems not fully equivalent - same with any Consuming functional interface

Tags: java, generics, method-reference, functional-interface

I am having a java compiler error that I don't understand. It seems that Consumer< ? > and Consumer< T > (with T extends Object) are not equivalent in method signature arguments. Please check out the code below:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class MyClass {

    public void joker(Consumer<?> fct) {}
    public <T> void generic(Consumer<T> fct) {}
    public void myConsumer(String s) {}

    public void doesNotCompile()
    {
        joker(this::myConsumer); // COMPILE ERROR : (In Eclipse : ) The type MyClass does not define myConsumer(Object) that is applicable here
        generic(this::myConsumer); // Works fine : how come are "T" and "?" not equivalent here ?

        // The following also works fine as usual :
        Consumer<String> cs = this::myConsumer;
        joker(cs);

        joker((String s) -> myConsumer(s));
    }

}
```

The error is a bit different when I compile the code via command-line rather than in Eclipse:

```
D:\>javac -Xdiags:verbose MyClass.java
MyClass.java:11: error: method joker in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;
                joker(this::myConsumer);
                ^
  required: Consumer<?>
  found:    this::myConsumer
  reason: argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      method myConsumer in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types
        required: String
        found:    Object
        reason: argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to String
1 error
```

It is slightly clearer but I still don't get the point. Note you get an analog error with java.util.function.Function but not with java.util.function.Supplier. I therefore believe the error occurs for any functional interface taking in a parameter.

Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something here? In case of the latter (most likely), can someone tell the reason of such a behavior design?

I feel that there is something going wrong with type inference. I also barely know that JVM handles lambdas and method reference differently (AFAIK via MethodHandler). But to be honest, I am just confused.

Help? ¯\ *(ツ)*/¯

Comment: `this::myConsumer` is being considered as a `Consumer<Object>`. `Consumer<?> consumer = this::myConsumer;` won't work

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR;** The compiler effectively forbids to pass any value other than `null` into a `Consumer<?>`. And thus the usage of `Consumer<?>` is literally none.

Try this in your `joker` method:

```
fct.accept(new Object());
```

You'll see that it won't compile, because the compiler can't ensure that the passed `Consumer` really can accept `Object`s. But using `null` works, as it is the only valid value for all `Object`s:

```
fct.accept(null);
```

You can overcome this limitation by using unchecked casts, but they are **really** discouraged, as you will like run into a `ClassCastException`.

Keep in mind that `Consumer<Object>` is **not equal** to `Consumer<?>`. The prior allows any `Object` to be passed into it, whereas the latter doesn't accept anything! (except `null` of course)

Your other example which works "fine":

```
joker((String s) -> myConsumer(s));
```

But under the hood you're also making use of unchecked casts. You're implicitly casting `s` from `Object` to `String`. It is almost equivalent to writing:

```
joker(s -> myConsumer((String) s));
```

Or even this (Because `s` is only known to be an `Object`):

```
joker((Object s) -> myConsumer((String) s));
```

To your other question why `T` and `?` are not the same. `T` is a generic type and the compiler tries to narrow it down to the most specific type. In the case of `generic(this::myConsumer)`, `T` will be `String`, if the compiler can't infer the type, it will simply use `Object` so it is similar to `Consumer<Object>`, but **not** `Consumer<?>`

All in all, using `Consumer<?>` will likely never have a real use case, because without any nasty hacks you can only pass `null` into it. And what would be the use of that?

Answer (score 1):

`joker(this::myConsumer);` uses the method reference `this::myConsumer` in a context that forces the target type to be `Consumer<?>`, where the compiler is forced to use `Object` for `?`. Given that, there would need to be a signature of `myConsumer` that takes `Object`, and there isn't any in `MyClass`.

> how come are "T" and "?" not equivalent here ?

That is not the problem. See the following code, which compiles:

```
Consumer<String> jokerConsumer = this::myConsumer;
joker(jokerConsumer);
```

The only difference is that the method reference (with its target type) has a compatible method in `MyClass`.

Besides, if you add `public void myConsumer(Object s) {}` to your class, the original `joker(this::myConsumer);` compiles just fine.

The generic method works simply because `T` is inferred to be the same as the type of the parameter to `myConsumer`, which puts an end to the problem.

So that shows two ways of solving the current problem. In short, this is a question of the method reference's target type (in the context of the method invocation) being compatible with the signature of the referenced method.